# Is there a way to automatically change a list/dict name?

Tags: python, csv

here is my problem.

I have a lot of csv with a lot of data, and I want to extract few lines in function of the year. It's important for me to separate each years, so I decided to create various list/dict for each year and extract the data I'm interested in.

The problem is there isn't the same number of years for each file, and create manually the lists /dict'll be way too long.

In my code I extracted the minimal and maximal years and now I want to create a loop to rename the list/dict for each year i have.

I havn't any idea of which function i can use .. Maybe i just mistaken and my logic wasn't good right now ?   Here is how I extracted how many years I have in my file.

```
import csv
with open('file.csv') as rawFile:
reader = csv.DictReader(rawFile, delimiter=';')

firstDate = next(reader)["date"]
currentYear = firstDate.split('/')[-1]
minYear=int(currentYear)
for row in reader :
    date=row["date"]       

maxiYear=int(date.split('/')[-1])

nbList=maxiYear-minYear 
print(nbList)
```

thank you very much for your help and sorry for my english, had a long time without speaking this language.

EDIT : My table structure :

| Date | Q |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/1800 | 120.5 |
| 02/02/1800 | 150.2 |
| 03/02/1800 | 85.3 |
| 04/02/1800 | 75.5 |

Comment: Could you give a shot example of the CSV file structure and the structure of table you would like to get?
Is there a reason why you want to do this in python and not with unix utilities (sh, awk, cut, ...)?
If you want to use python, why not use pandas.DataFrame?

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you want to accomplish. Would you like to separate the rows of your CSV in several lists, and put them in a dict by year, something like `{'2019': [<list of 2019 rows>], '2020': [l<list of 2020 rows>] ...}`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i want to do thierry Lathuille, and if i don't use pandas.DataFrame it's because i'm a beginner and i havn't heard about it, but now i'll look for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We create a dict with years as keys, and lists of corresponding rows as values.

We can use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)
that will create empty lists on the fly when we access a key that doesn't exist yet.

We just have to iterate on the rows and append each one to the list for its year:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict


with open('file.csv') as rawFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(rawFile, delimiter=';')

    rows_by_year = defaultdict(list)
    for row in reader:
        year = row["date"].split('/')[-1]
        rows_by_year[year].append(row)
```